# Snake game using arrays

Tags: java

I am making a snake game using arrays. I want to store `x` and `y` coordinates of every snake body so that I could use it later for collision or something.

I made the value(?) of `xCoordinate[row or col]` is increased or decreased by 1 every key pressed, but I don't think that is the right way to store coordinates. Plus, a key pressed only changes direction so it is only increased or decreased once. That even doesn't work.

What should I do in order to store coordinates?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;   //allows us to use the scanner package

public class KeyInput {

    static MainBoard b; //initialize board named b

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        final int ROWS = 25, COLS = 25;
        int row=0, col =0;
        boolean finished = false;
        int[] xCoordsFood, yCoordsFood;
        int[] xCoordsSnake, yCoordsSnake;

        b = new MainBoard(ROWS, COLS); 

        xCoordsFood = new int[25];
        yCoordsFood = new int[25];
        xCoordsSnake = new int[25];
        yCoordsSnake = new int[25];

        // MAIN GAME LOOP
        while(!finished){
            //get random location of food
            int loc = rand.nextInt(25);
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                xCoordsFood[i] = rand.nextInt(25);
                yCoordsFood[i] = rand.nextInt(25);
            } 

            b.putPeg("red",row,col);

            b.displayMessage("Key: " + b.getKey()); 
            if (b.getKey() == 'w'){
                row --;
                xCoordsSnake[row] =- 1;
                System.out.print(xCoordsSnake[row]);
            }
            if (b.getKey() == 'a'){
                col--;
                yCoordsSnake[col] =- 1;
                System.out.print(yCoordsSnake[col]);
            }
            if (b.getKey() == 's'){
                row ++;
                xCoordsSnake[row] =+ 1;
                System.out.print(xCoordsSnake[row]);
            }
            if (b.getKey() == 'd'){
                col++;
                yCoordsSnake[col] =+ 1;
                System.out.print(yCoordsSnake[col]);
            }
            // DELAY SO THAT ANIMATION IS SLOWED DOWN
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
            }
            // CHECK IF SQUARE GOES OUT OF BOUNDS
            if (row<0 || row>=ROWS || col<0 || col>=COLS){
                finished = true;
            }
            System.out.println(b.getKey());     
        }
        b.displayMessage("GAME OVER!"); 

    }
}
```

Comment: formatting fixed

Answer (score 0):

As your data structure has variable size, you should use a data structure efficient for adding new elements, like a linked list.

Also, you do not have to move all values in the array because the parts of the snake will assume the position of other parts. So, you just need to remove the tail and add a new head at each movement for example.

It's important to think a lot about the problem before coding to come with easier and more efficient solutions.

Comment: His data structure does not have variable size, where did you get that idea? He has a game board, the snake moves around the board, and they lose the game if the snake tries to go outside of the borders.

Comment: He can implement the game just saving the snake coordinates and checking for collision with itself and with boards. There is no point for saving the whole board (maximum coordinate values). In the worst case the snake will take the whole board.